# Reversing Program in C

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

int Number,rightDigit = 0;


 NSLog(@"Enter the Number");
 scanf("%d",&Number);

 while (Number != 0) {

     rightDigit = Number % 10;
     printf("%d",rightDigit);
     Number = Number / 10;
    }



    printf("\nright number is %d",rightDigit);
    printf("\n number is %d",Number);
}
return 0;
}
```

I have reversed the number that the user had entered and i have to reverse it again so that it becomes what it was before.
For example: i typed 123 and it reversed it 321 and i want to reverse it again so it becomes 123 again.
how can i get my reversed number in integer variable?
How can i do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? and what were the results of that try?

Comment: `321` ---> reversed becomes `123`, not `113`. Also, are (not) you missing a `)` in `printf("%d",rightDigit;` ?

Comment: so run your reversing code twice. once on the original string, then again on the reversed string.

Comment: @MarcB how can get reversed number in integer variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at how you reverse:

1. You take a copy of the rightmost digit by using `%`
2. You then "shift right" your number, using `/`, and the rightmost digit drops off
3. Display the copy of the rightmost digit you've extracted
4. Repeat till done

Now you want to create a new number which is the reverse of the original. Following your above algorithm pattern could you not:

1. "Shift left" the reversed number you are building up, introducing a new `0` digit at the right
2. Replace the just inserted rightmost `0` with the digit you wish to insert
3. Repeat

Each of these steps just requires a simple operation like your first algorithm, and you can combine both loops into one so you construct your reversed number instead of (or as well as) printing it out.

HTH